# How to dynamic change title?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to change the title `titleItemPanel` of the view `ItemsPanelComponent` depending on what action is apply by `editItem()` in `ItemsPageComponent`. But, I have nested component: `ItemsPageComponent` -> `ItemsMapComponent` -> `ItemsPanelComponent`.  The event `getItemPanelTitle`  is emitted by the child (`ItemsPanelComponent`), and this event should be taken by the grandparent (`ItemsPageComponent`). This event should be given to the parent (`ItemsMapComponent`), and must pass it to the grandparent(`ItemsPageComponent`).

`ItemsPageComponent`:

```js
export class ItemsPageComponent {
  @Output() isTitleCreateItem = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  
  editItem(itemId: string, event) {
   ...
   this.isTitleCreateItem = !this.isTitleCreateItem;
  }
```

```html
    <button md-icon-button
       (click)="editItem(item.id, $event)">
            <md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon>
    </button>
```

`ItemsPanelComponent`:

```js
export class ItemsPanelComponent {
public titleItemPanel: string;
 ...
 
  getItemPanelTitle(event: boolean) {
    this.titleItemPanel = event ? 'Create' : 'Edit';
  }
}
```

```html
<h4 (isTitleCreateItem)="getItemPanelTitle($event)" class="panel__title"> 
    {{titleItemPanel}}
</h4>
```

Comment: Use `@Input()` on your `ItemsPanelComponent` and pass `isCreateItem` value

Comment: different ways to do component interaction refer https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @penleychan, @Input() isCreateItem: boolean; - it's try? I get an error Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want change the "title" of the document in the navigator Use [Title](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title#title)

```
public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**ItemsPanelComponent:**

```
export class ItemsPanelComponent {
 this.title;

  get itemsPanelTitle() {
   this.title= this.isCreateItem ? 'Create' : 'Edit';
  }
}
<h4 class="panel__title">{{title}}</h4>
```

This works for me.